# How to search in solr for or'ed attributes

Tags: http, solr, full-text-search

I have query one:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/example/select?q=title:"King Kong"&wt=json
```

That results with one doc returned.

I have query two:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/example/select?q=title:"Snow Queen"&wt=json
```

That results with one doc returned.

I am trying to follow this tutorial:

http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html

That as I understand it suggest that I should do:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/example/select?q=title:"King Kong" or title:"Snow Queen"&wt=json
```

However it yields 0 results. Actually it errors with this payload:

```
metadata: [
    "error-class",
    "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
    "root-error-class",
    "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"
],
msg: "undefined field text",
code: 400
```

Same things happen if I try to replace 'or' with 'and' or add parenthesis.

But if do:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/example/select?&q=title:"King Kong" title:"Snow Queen"&wt=json
```

It works, result is or'ed properly.

In other words what is proper syntax in http request to pass or'ed/and'ed queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By accident I learnt solution:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/example/select?q=title:"King Kong" OR title:"Snow Queen"&wt=json
```

Or more complex case:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/example/select?q=title:"King Kong" OR (title:"Snow Queen" AND type:"Fairy tale")&wt=json
```

In short upper-case letters do have meaning. ;-)